# Is the documentation for SerialPort.Write(byte[], int, int) misleading?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm asking this in case I've been using SerialPort.Write() incorrectly. I'm pretty certain I haven't, but you never know...

The documentation for [SerialPort.Write(byte[], int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx) states:

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters.
>   ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or
>   '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to
>   UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

This is identical to comments in the documentation for [SerialPort.Write(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8.aspx) and [SerialPort.Write(char[], int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1050fs1h.aspx).

It's been like that for many years, but I've never really noticed it before. I've always happily used `SerialPort.Write(byte[], int, int)` to send binary data with values above 0x7f. I find it strange that the documentation for something that sends a byte array is talking about characters.

Is it just me, or is there something a bit wrong with the documentation there?

Comment: It seems to me that remark should only be at the `char[]` and `string` overloads of those methods.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking copy-paste error. But occasionally I realise I've been doing something wrong for years, and I've got away with it by luck.

Comment: I agree with CodeCaster and as you said it is probably just a copy-paste error on the part of MS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's misleading.  (Not sure what else you could want from an answer.  Is this really a question?)

Comment: I was worried that I might have been using SerialPort.Write() incorrectly, and it was just working by accident.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is definitely wrong. If you decompile `Write(char[], int, int)` you will see

```
byte[] bytes = this.Encoding.GetBytes(buffer, offset, count);
this.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // This is the Write(byte[], int, int) method
```

Whereas the `Write(byte[], int, int)` method just contains:

```
this.internalSerialStream.Write(buffer, offset, count, this.writeTimeout);
```

So it's clear that no ASCII encoding occurs in this method.